# filter_var or mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I would like to know which is stronger `filter_var` or `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

To be more specific.

Option1:

```
//Course Title
$ctitle = trim($_POST['courseTitle']);
$clean_ctitle = filter_var($ctitle, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Option2:

```
//Course Title
$ctitle = trim($_POST['courseTitle']);
$clean_ctitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ctitle);
```

I also know about prepared statements but I want to filter the data coming in before hand. If there is an alternative, let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stronger'? Which is better at escaping characters, or which is more efficient?

Comment: I think `preferred statement` is a typo for `prepared statement`?

Answer (score 5):

They don't achieve the same goal, you will use `filter_var($ctitle, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` to get rid of unwanted special characters, while `mysqli_real_escape_string` is a transport encoding to apply needed transformations so that what you will store will be exactly what you provided, avoiding SQL error or injections.

Typically you will first use `filter_var()` (or any built-in functionality in the framework you use) to enforce the format and allowed characters rules from external input (form data, URL parameters...). Then, when it comes to save the data you validated, you will use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to inject the data into your MySQL string.

To summarize,

- `filter_var()` is about filtering and validating input data.
- `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is about escaping data before using it in a MySQL string.

You're not supposed to choose between them, you're supposed to use both ;-)

Comment: @TimDev likely someone who prefers prepared statements

Comment: He/She undid them. Nitpickers who don't read actual questions *rolls eyes.

Answer (score 2):

`filter_var` and  `mysqli_real_escape_string` are two different things.
You haven't really said what you are using the strings for but filter functions are OK, but some of them are more validators than filters.

The FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter option removes tags and remove or encode special characters from a string. It's not good sanitation for mysql.

So it depends what you are sanitizing for.

If you are looking to sanitize your strings before using them in MySQL queries, you should indeed use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.  But as you said prepared statements (PDO) is better.

Comment: thank you. I am using the data collected from a contact form to send out an email to us  nothing is being stored in the database here. Out of curiosity, why would  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING not be good for mysql sanitation

Comment: Because it will corrupt the data.  You sanitize your data based on the target. So you don't sanitize HTML for your mysql goal. You simply save the HTML. And if necessary escape it when needed.